# How to get records where csv column contains all the values of a filter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a table some departments tagged with user as

```
User   | Department
user1  | IT,HR,House Keeping
user2  | HR,House Keeping
user3  | IT,Finance,HR,Maintainance
user4  | Finance,HR,House Keeping
user5  | IT,HR,Finance
```

i have created a  SP that take parameter varchar(max) as  filter (i dynamically merged if in C# code)

in the sp i creat a temp table for the selected filters eg; if user select IT & Finance & HR

i merged the string as IT##Finance##HR (in C#) & call the sp with this parameter

in SP i make a temp table as

```
FilterValue
IT
Finance
HR
```

now the issue  how can i get the records that contains all the departments taged with them 
(users that are associated with all the values in temp table) to get

```
User   | Department
user3  | IT,Finance,HR,Maintainance
user5  | IT,HR,Finance
```

as optput

please suggest an optimised way to achive this filtering

Comment: Why would you even consider storing data that way? Comma delimited lists are a sign that you need a related table. Fix your design before you go any further.

Comment: i had already raised the iisues in design ... but till the design is not change (obviously less chances) i have to work on it. please suggest the solution considering this design

Answer (score 1):

This design is beyond horrible -- you should really change this to use truly relational design with a dependent table.

That said, if you are not in a position to change the design, you can limp around the problem with XML, and it might give you OK performance.

Try something like this (replace '@test' with your table name as needed...).  You won't need to even create your temp table -- this will jimmy your comma-delimited string around into XML, which you can then use XQuery against directly:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (usr int, department varchar(1000))

insert into @test (usr, department)
values (1, 'IT,HR,House Keeping')
insert into @test (usr, department)
values (2, 'HR,House Keeping')
insert into @test (usr, department)
values (3, 'IT,Finance,HR,Maintainance')
insert into @test (usr, department)
values (4, 'Finance,HR,House Keeping')
insert into @test (usr, department)
values (5, 'IT,HR,Finance')

;WITH departments (usr, department, depts)
AS
(
    SELECT usr, department, CAST(NULLIF('<department><dept>' + REPLACE(department, ',', '</dept><dept>') + '</dept></department>', '<department><dept></dept></department>') AS xml)
    FROM @test
)
SELECT departments.usr, departments.department
FROM departments
WHERE departments.depts.exist('/department/dept[text()[1] eq "IT"]') = 1
    AND departments.depts.exist('/department/dept[text()[1] eq "HR"]') = 1
    AND departments.depts.exist('/department/dept[text()[1] eq "Finance"]') = 1
```

Comment: hey filter selection  is dynamic so how can i build where clause : WHERE departments.depts.exist('/department/dept[text()[1] eq "IT"]') = 1
    AND departments.depts.exist('/department/dept[text()[1] eq "HR"]') = 1
    AND departments.depts.exist('/department/dept[text()[1] eq "Finance"]') = 1
-------------------------------------------------------------please suggest how to build /department/dept[text()[1] eq "Finance"] dynamically  if that was not the case i can use PATINDEX without any need xml parsing

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that your design is, um, not ideal, and given the fact that it *may* change, as per your comment, one is not too motivated to find a really fascinating solution for the present situation.

Still, you *can* have one that at least works correctly (I think) and meets the situation. Here's what I've come up with:

```
;
WITH
  UserDepartment ([User], Department) AS (
    SELECT 'user1', 'IT,HR,House Keeping' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user2', 'HR,House Keeping' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user3', 'IT,Finance,HR,Maintainance' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user4', 'Finance,HR,House Keeping' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'user5', 'IT,HR,Finance'
  ),
  Filter (FilterValue) AS (
    SELECT 'IT' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Finance' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'HR'
  ),
  CSVSplit AS (
    SELECT
      ud.*,
      --x.node.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
      x.Value AS aDepartment
    FROM UserDepartment ud
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(',', ud.Department)) x
  )
SELECT
  c.[User],
  c.Department
FROM CSVSplit c
  INNER JOIN Filter f ON c.aDepartment = f.FilterValue
GROUP BY
  c.[User],
  c.Department
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Filter)
```

The first two CTEs are just sample tables, the rest of the query is the solution proper.

The `CSVSplit` CTE uses a [`Split` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco/314917#314917) that splits a comma-separated list into a set of items and returns them as a table. The entire CTE turns the row set of the form

```
-----  ---------------------------
user1  department1,department2,...
...    ...
```

into this:

```
-----  -----------
user1  department1
user1  department2
...    ...
```

The main SELECT joins the normalised row set with the filter table and selects rows where the number of matches exactly equals the number of items in the filter table. *(Note: this implies there's no identical names in `UserDepartment.Department`)*.